# I want to call json array in android and add it to spinner

Tags: android

This is my json array

```
{"options":["Large","Medium","Small","Xtra Large"]}
```

Spinner Code :

```
spinner spin;

spin = findViewById(R.id.spin);

private ArrayList<String> colorAttr = new ArrayList<>();
colorAttributes = attributesObject.getString("options");
colorAttr.add(colorAttributes);
spin.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProductPageActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, colorAttr));
```

This is what i have tried but it doesn't Work

I want to set Large, Medium, etc to Spinner But it is not working

Comment: Please follow this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For you to get the Strings, you need to first get the Array known as *options* in your case, then you can loop through it to get the Strings like we did below.

```
spinner spin;
spin = findViewById(R.id.spin);

private ArrayList<String> colorAttr = new ArrayList<>();/*I assume this is where you want to store what you want to display in the spinner.*/

colorAttributes = attributesObject.getString("options");/*I also assume you can access the "Options" from "attributesObject" and I want to believe that "attributesObject" is an Object? precisely a JSONObject.*/
```

> **So we can have like below:**

```
/*This is the only thing you missed, first we get the Array, then loop through it to get the Strings.*/
JSONArray opt = attributesObject.getJSONArray("options");
 for(int i=0; i< opt.length(); i++){
    colorAttr.add(opt.getString(i));
}

spin.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProductPageActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, colorAttr));
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `attributesObject.getJSONArray("options");` to get the array.